# saxon: problem reusing XsltTransformer object

Tags: saxon

Using Saxon-B, I'm trying to follow the javadoc and serially reuse an XsltTransformer object.

I'm thwarted by:

```
Error 
  XTDE1490: Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI, or write to a URI
  that has been read: file:/Users/benson/x/btweb/web_2_0/sites/us/errors/404/404.xml.prepared
2011-03-22 11:06:23,830 [main] ERROR btweb.compiler.CompileSite - Site compilation terminated with error.
btweb.compiler.CompilerException: Error running transform Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI, or write to a URI that has been read: file:/Users/benson/x/btweb/web_2_0/sites/us/errors/404/404.xml.prepared
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably Saxon-B bug. You can find more information [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1743787&group_id=29872&atid=397617). According to this site "Fixed in 8.9.0.4".

Comment: I'm using version 9, so it can't be that.

Comment: Try to use this fixed 8.9.0.4 version (http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-B/8.9.0.4/). Maybe bug was fixed, but only for 8.9 group (I know it sounds unbelievable).